# How to fix responsive table issues in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4

In one of my project, I'm trying Bootstrap 4. In a list page of the project I use to HTML table along with Bootstrap 4 available table classes to make the table responsive, but after a certain period of time ( when tables width crosses window width ) in large screen, Bootstrap responsive table classes are not working. I've tried all of the possible Bootstrap Responsive Table class. Here is my code behind the table:

```
<div class="card-body" id="loadContent">
    <div class="table-responsive-xl table-responsive-lg table-responsive-md table-responsive-sm table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="professionalTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Specialization</th>
                    <th>PCN</th>
                    <th>Grant Type</th>
                    <th>Total Grant</th>
                    <th>Payment Amount</th>
                    <th>Grant Purpose Amount</th>
                    <th>Date Expedenture</th>
                    <th>Company</th>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>Month</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Example 1</td>
                    <td>Example 2</td>
                    <td>Example 3</td>
                    <td>Example 4</td>
                    <td>Example 5</td>
                    <td>Example 6</td>
                    <td>Example 7</td>
                    <td>Example 8</td>
                    <td>Example 9</td>
                    <td>Example 10</td>
                    <td>Example 11</td>
                    <td>Example 12</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And Here is a screenshot of the problem using dummy data:
[image]

Did you notice the width of the table content crosses the width of the window?

Can anyone tell how can I fix this issue? I mean currently the horizontal scrollbar is created by the browser (as it crosses the width of the window), but I want the scrollbar relative to the table itself.

Comment: Since you haven't posted a [mcve], it's not actually possible to answer your question. All we can with your code is guess around, no more. The code you posted works exactly as expected without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should nest the code inside a  tag or  and specify the width.
for example:   `<div class="row"><div class="col-md-10"><div class="card-body" id="loadContent">...</div></div>` or

```
<main class="col-sm-9 offset-sm-3 col-md-10 offset-md-2 pt-3"><div class="card-body" id="loadContent">...</main>
```

Hope it works!